# SymmetricDS can not register client

Tags: java, spring-boot, symmetricds

When I start my client it can not register, the server says the following:

```
WARN  [http-nio-8080-exec-3] o.j.s.s.impl.RegistrationService - Cannot register a client node unless a node group link exists so the registering node can receive configuration updates.  Please add a group link where the source group id is server and the target group id is client
WARN  [http-nio-8080-exec-3] o.j.s.web.RegistrationUriHandler - client:001:? was not allowed to register.
```

The servers tables:

```
SELECT * FROM SYM_NODE_GROUP;
NODE_GROUP_ID   DESCRIPTION     CREATE_TIME     LAST_UPDATE_BY      LAST_UPDATE_TIME  
server  null    null    null    null
client  null    null    null    null

SELECT * FROM SYM_NODE_GROUP_LINK;
SOURCE_NODE_GROUP_ID    TARGET_NODE_GROUP_ID    DATA_EVENT_ACTION   SYNC_CONFIG_ENABLED     IS_REVERSIBLE   CREATE_TIME     LAST_UPDATE_BY      LAST_UPDATE_TIME  
server  client  W   1   0   null    null    null
client  server  P   1   0   null    null    null
```

The client is getting an 500 error because the server can not register the client.

What do i miss?

Comment: Are there hidden spaces in db values for ‘server’ and ‘client’, maybe? For example ‘server ‘ or ‘client ‘

Comment: Are there records in sym_node and sym_node_security at the server that represent the client node?  If so, is the sym_node record enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both client and Server was missing the sync url registration

```
  @Bean
  public ServletRegistrationBean<SymmetricServlet> symServlet() {
    ServletRegistrationBean<SymmetricServlet> bean = new ServletRegistrationBean<>(new SymmetricServlet(), "/sync/*");
    bean.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    return bean;
  }
```